# Block Citrix User To Access TIF from IE

Tags: windows, security, citrix, permissions

There is a restriction to not be able to access C:\ on a citrix environment I'm currently looking at. It is possible to circumvent this measure partially by looking at the temporary internet files from IE which are located on C. Is it possible to disallow users in a citrix environment to access their temporary internet files from Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may restrict access to the Internet Explorer menu option:

```
Group Policy:  
Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Control Panel  
Setting: Disable the General page  
Value: Enabled
```

Actually you should probably disallow most of the Tools > Options property pages if the environment is restricted.  You may want to give that some thought.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't really disallow access to these files.

What you can do, however, is [hide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289) and [restrict](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978514.aspx) the drive so they won't be able to navigate is through explorer. It's not bulletproof (because it relies on application supporting the limitation) though.